# How to fix "this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition" error?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am using cargo on a Chromebook Lenovo Duet 5. I have this error just as I try to code something a little more complex. I was trying to import an image package and got this error:

```
this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.
```

I suspect that maybe that image package is only built for x86_64 and I just happen to be learning Rust on ARM. I tried to build cargo from source using the binary cargo I have, but that also has the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not a platform difference; you simply have an old version. The 2021 language edition was added with Rust release version 1.56.0, in October 2021. You need to install a Rust version that is at least that new.

The recommended way to install and maintain a Rust toolchain is with [Rustup](https://rustup.rs/). I can personally confirm that it will work on ARM Chromebook Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what helped was to select a particular rust toolchain:

```
rustup override set nightly
```

Dependencies defined in workspace needs to be compatible with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using the rustup installer. This is an unattended install:

```
export RUSTUP_HOME=/opt/rust/rustup 
export CARGO_HOME=/opt/rust/cargo
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- --default-toolchain stable --profile default --no-modify-path -y
export PATH="/opt/rust/cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

The 2 HOME directories are the install locations.